# Oracle named parameters

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

How can I use keywords with Oracle named parameters syntax ? The following gives me 'ORA-00936: missing expression' because of the 'number'-argument:

```
select  b.g3e_fid
    ,   a.g3e_fid
    , sdo_nn_distance( 1)
from acn a, b$gc_fitface_s b
where mdsys.sdo_nn ( geometry1 => a.g3e_geometry, geometry2 => b.g3e_geometry, param => 'sdo_num_res=1', number=>1) = 'TRUE' and b.g3e_fid = 57798799;
```

If I run it without named parameters it is fine.

thanks, Steef

Comment: is the parameter name 'number'? isn't it a reserved word?

Comment: Yes. Can I use named parameters with reserved words ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can get around the reserved word issue in your call by enclosing the name in double quotes as @AvrajitRoy suggested, i.e. `... "NUMBER"=>1) = 'TRUE'...`, you aren't actually achieving much. Oracle is letting you refer to the parameters by name but it isn't doing anything with that information.

`MDSYS.SDO_NN` is a [spatial operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_operat.htm#SPATL1032), not a direct call to a function. There is a function backing it up - you can see from the schema scripts for MDSYS that it's actually calling `prtv_idx.nn` - but the names of the formal parameters of that function are not relevant. With some digging you can see those are actually called `geom`, `geom2`, `mask` etc., and there isn't one called `number` (and you can't have a formal parameter called `number`, even quoting it, as far as I can tell).

The formal parameters to the *operator* are not named, and are effectively passed through positionally. You can't skip an argument by naming the others, as you can with a function/procedure with arguments that have default values.

So that means you can call the parameters anything you want in your call; changing the names of the first three parameters in your call to something random won't stop it working.

It also means naming them in the call is a bit pointless, but if you're just trying to document the call then you can use some other meaningful name rather than 'number' if you don't want to quote it.

Answer (score -1):

Hello as mentined in you question . There are two ways in which u can eliminate this RESERVED keyword ISSUE.

1) Use "" to use any RESERVED key word for calling. But remember this is not a good coding practice.
Eg >

```
SELECT b.g3e_fid ,
  a.g3e_fid ,
  sdo_nn_distance( 1)
FROM acn a,
  b$gc_fitface_s b
WHERE mdsys.sdo_nn 
( geometry1 => a.g3e_geometry, 
 geometry2 => b.g3e_geometry, 
 "param" => 'sdo_num_res=1', 
 "NUMBER"=>1) = 'TRUE'
AND b.g3e_fid = 57798799;
```

2) Secondly you can just call the function without using "=>" as shown below

Eg >

```
SELECT b.g3e_fid ,
  a.g3e_fid ,
  sdo_nn_distance( 1)
FROM acn a,
  b$gc_fitface_s b
WHERE mdsys.sdo_nn 
( a.g3e_geometry, 
 b.g3e_geometry, 
 'sdo_num_res=1', 
 1) = 'TRUE'
AND b.g3e_fid = 57798799;
```